# Class being converted to 1-dimensional array

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to write a class library and I am getting the following error:
"Value of type 'WorkMateLib.Login' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of WorkMateLib.Login'"

The code of the classes is as follows:

```
Public Class Logins
    Public CurrentUser As Login()
    Public Sub New()
        CurrentUser = New Login()
    End Sub
    Public Function Authenticate(ByVal id As String, ByVal pw As String)
        Dim adpt As New WorkMateDataSetTableAdapters.LoginsTableAdapter
        For Each k As WorkMateDataSet.LoginsRow In adpt.GetDataByUserName(id)
            If String.Equals(k.UserPW, pw) Then
                CurrentUser = New Login(k.UserName, k.UserPW, k.UserType)
                Return CurrentUser
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next
        CurrentUser = Nothing
        Return Nothing
    End Function

End Class

Public Class Login
    Private _UserName As String
    Private _UserPW As String
    Private _UserType As String
    Property UserName
        Get
            Return _UserName
        End Get
        Set(value)
            _UserName = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Property UserPW
        Get
            Return _UserPW
        End Get
        Set(value)
            _UserPW = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Property UserType
        Get
            Return _UserType
        End Get
        Set(value)
            _UserType = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Sub New()
        UserName = ""
        UserPW = ""
        UserType = ""
    End Sub
    Public Sub New(ByVal Namee As String, ByVal pw As String, ByVal typee As String)
        UserName = Namee
        UserPW = pw
        UserType = typee
    End Sub

End Class
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should just be

```
Dim CurrentUser as Login
```

Adding the `()` to the end of the Type changes it to an Array of the Type.

You should really be declaring the variable as

```
Dim CurrentUser As Login = New Login
```

As this will instantiate an instance of the `Login` object and assign it to the `CurrentUser` Variable. Currently you are just creating a Variable that is a `Login` type but giving it no value.

Comment: Thank you that solved it, however, when I try to initialize and use the logins.CurrentUser I get and error that it is not set to an instance, this is solved by using logins.currentuser= new Servicel.Login.  COuld you please explain why this happend, what modification is required.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but why cant it be achieved by placing the CUrrentuser= new login in the Logins Class Constructor itself?

Comment: because what if you create the class through a different constructor that doesn't initialize the variable.

Comment: So it is a logical block placed by MS.  FIne.  Thanks for sharing information with me.